# Boxed minitoc with each chapter

Tags: minitoc

[image]

How can I do a boxed minitoc at the beginning of any chapter like this.

It is too hard for me.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}
\newcommand\chapnamefont{\huge}
\newcommand\chaptitlefont{\LARGE}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\startcontents\bfseries\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
  [{%
    \filleft{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}\\
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.75\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      width=\linewidth,
      enhanced,
      top=10pt,
      nobeforeafter,
      outer arc=0pt,
      arc=0pt,
      boxrule=0.6pt,
      colback=white,
      overlay={
        \node[anchor=west,fill=white,inner xsep=6pt] 
          at ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west) 
          {Sommaire};
      }
    ]
      \printcontents{}{1}{}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.25\textwidth}
      \filleft
      \chapnumfont\thechapter
    \end{minipage}\\[10pt]
    {\chaptitlefont#1}
    }%
  ]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\startcontents\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\chaptitlefont#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\section{Test section one one}
\section{Test section one two}
\section{Test section one three}


\chapter{Test chapter two}
\section{Test section two one}
\section{Test section two two}
\section{Test section two three}
\section{Test section two four}
\section{Test section two five}

\end{document}
```

The general ToC:

[image]

The partial ToC for chapter one:

[image]

The partial ToC for chapter two:

[image]

## Remarks

- [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) was used to change the formatting for the chapter headings.
- [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) was used to produce the partial ToCs.
- [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) was used to produce the frame and title around the partial ToCs.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina When I add `\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
`, minitoc not exactly. How can I use this command?

Comment: @minthao_2011 I don't get any problemas adding the line you mentioned, Please feel free to open a fresh new question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I done. First, I put the line before `\begin{document}

`